# Github Pages: adding an if condition in index.html

Tags: if-statement, github, conditional-statements, github-pages, blogs

I have a blog created on Github Pages using [Jekyll Now](https://www.jekyllnow.com/)

The default Index.html looks like this

```
---
layout: default
---

<div class="posts">
  {% for post in site.posts %}
        <article class="post">

          <h2><a href="{{ site.baseurl }}{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a></h2>

          <div class="entry">
            {{ post.excerpt }}
          </div>

          <a href="{{ site.baseurl }}{{ post.url }}" class="read-more">Read More</a>
        </article>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

This creates a landing page where the titles of all the posts you have made in the _posts directory are displayed with a link.

Looking at the `{% for ... %}` & `{% endfor %}` & the final static HTML, it seems as if when building the page, the for tag is actually iterated & the final HTML contains a list of actual titles.

I want to change this so that not all posts are listed. I do not want to list any post whose title contains the string "BEINGWRITTEN"

I tried stuff like

```
{% for post in site.posts %}
    {% if (post.title.indexOf('BEINGWRITTEN') == -1) %}
        <article class="post">
...
        </article>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Also tried with includes instead of indexOf, that also doesn't work. Both cases, I don't see any posts linked at all on the landing page.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this by adding a category in the front matter of the page I don't want included.

i.e.
category: noshow

Then changed the index.html to

```
   {% for post in site.posts %}

      {% unless post.category == "noshow" %}

          .....

      {%endunless}

   {%endfor}
```